Problem resizing Ubuntu disk (Proxmox VM)
I am trying to increase the size of the hard disk of my Lubuntu 20.04 VM (on Proxmox 8.2.5). I used the resize option in the PVE UI, then started the VM and used cfdisk to resize the disk to use the newly-created free space (increasing from 122GB to 202GB). cfdisk now shows the partition as the correct size, but when I try to use pvresize to resize the volume it tells me that it can't find the physical volume.


Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

does this Proxmox article answer your question?

If I boot into Gparted I see this:
https://i.imgur.com/MrtIgI0.png

please add the image and your comment to your question. Comments are for asking you questions/clarification not your responses thereto.

Thanks for the link - this command seemed to work as an alternative to pvresize:
resize2fs /dev/sda1

This command seemed to work as an alternative to pvresize:
resize2fs /dev/sda1

